# webmin: Handles the name-based server www.my-domain.org on address *

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I need to configure our Apache web server to handle the domain name.

The phrase is like so:

```
webmin: Handles the name-based server www.my-domain.org on address *.
```

Why do we have:

```
Handles the name-based server www.my-domain.org on address *.
```

Why is it: `*.` and not `*.*`?

see the directives:

```
DocumentRoot "/sites/www.my_domain.org"        /usr/local/apache/conf/vhost/vhost.conf (67)
ServerName www.my_domain.org                   /usr/local/apache/conf/vhost/vhost.conf (68)
<Directory "/sites/www.my_domain.org">
 allow from all                               /usr/local/apache/conf/vhost/vhost.conf (70)
 Options None                                 /usr/local/apache/conf/vhost/vhost.conf (71)
 Require all granted                          /usr/local/apache/conf/vhost/vhost.conf (72)
</Directory>
```

**by the way**: in other cases - in the Overview on the Apache-Vhosts - in the webmin-frontend: it looks like so

```
Handles the name-based server www.the_domain_.org on all addresses
```

- on all adresses!?

this is different

look forward to hear from you

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we have: `Handles the name-based server www.my-domain.org on address *.` Why is it: `*.` and not `*.*`?

While I am not personally familiar with Webmin, at a guess `*.` is likely the "address" in an Apache `<VirtualHost>` directive. But more broadly, neither `*.` nor `*.*` make any sense. To have a virtual host listen on "all" IPs/ports, it would be e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    DocumentRoot "/www/default"
</VirtualHost>
```

> In other cases - in the Overview on the Apache-Vhosts - in the webmin-frontend: it looks like so
>
> `Handles the name-based server www.the_domain_.org on all addresses`
>
> on all addresses!?
>
> this is different

If an incorrect address was given, Webmin may not understand that the intention was "on all addresses".

---

*References*

[Apache VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)